# DateTime.ParseExact is raising the following error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

Tags: c#, datetime, sharepoint

I am building a console application for my sharepoint. now i have a DateTime field named "OrderLiveDeliveredDate" and i want to add months for it based on another field value named "CustomerOrderContractLengthmonth".

now the "OrderLiveDeliveredDate" date format will be as something as follow `{15/06/2018 00:00:00}`. so i wrote the following line of code to convert the field value to DateTime, then add the months:-

```
DateTime expiryDate = DateTime.ParseExact(item["OrderLiveDeliveredDate"].ToString(), "dd/mm/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).AddMonths(int.Parse(  item["CustomerOrderContractLengthmonth"].ToString()));
```

but this is raising the following exception :-

`String was not recognized as a valid DateTime`.

Comment: ParseExact needs to match exactly. If your date string is literally `{15/06/2018 00:00:00}`, then you should match to `"{dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss}"`

Comment: You need to use uppercase `M` for months. A lowercase `m` is minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) requires your format string to match exactly.

From the documentation,

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its DateTime equivalent using the specified format and culture-specific format information. The format of the string representation **must match the specified format exactly.**

(Emphasis mine.)

In your case, you would want `"{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}"` as your format string, assuming that `{15/06/2018 00:00:00}` was the actual value stored in `item["OrderLiveDeliveredDate"]`. If the braces aren't a member of the string, then `"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"` should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this?

```
DateTime expiryDate = DateTime.ParseExact("15/06/2018", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).AddMonths(int.Parse("2"));
```

I have got rid of time component from date string.If you must use the time component, try following...

```
DateTime expiryDate = DateTime.ParseExact("15/06/2018 00:00:00", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).AddMonths(int.Parse("2"));
```

Rextester for quick testing - http://rextester.com/HYEU95556

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Globalization;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            DateTime expiryDate = DateTime.ParseExact("15/06/2018", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).AddMonths(int.Parse("2"));
            DateTime expiryDate2 = DateTime.ParseExact("15/06/2018 00:00:00", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).AddMonths(int.Parse("2"));

            Console.WriteLine(expiryDate); //15.08.2018 00:00:00
            Console.WriteLine(expiryDate2); //15.08.2018 00:00:00
        }
    }
}
```